# Automated annotation adding for empty fields in a pdf file (empty form fields)

Tags: python, pdf, annotations

best saviors !

I'm actually working on a data science subject, where i just have empty legal documents (forms), the idea is to generate consistent dataset at first, but as you know the process should be automatized to fill thousands of documents : 
in this tutorial for instance : https://bostata.com/post/how_to_populate_fillable_pdfs_with_python/

you can find a way to add tags (with Adobe Acrobat DC) and to reuse them to populate your document (with Python), but adding tags manually has no use for me, as i need to use a huge number of documents and that those documents should evolve by time...

any magical way to detect and annotate any empty field in a PDF (preferably with Python)?

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

[PDFTron PDFNet SDK](https://www.pdftron.com/) is available on all platforms, with Python bindings, and you can find/edit fields.

https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples?platforms=linux#InteractiveForms

Comment: Thanks so much Ryan, i'll try it and give you a feedback.

Comment: Hello again Ryan, it seems like we were not talking about the same annotations and the same usage of those ones ! 
if you can just check the link above, in the tuto, the guy has used adobe acrobat DC to manually add tags in empty fields, and as i explained, it will be impossible for me without an automatized way, if i happen to use pdftron, should i re-implement the algorithme used in annotationTest sample ? any suggestions please ! i really need help

Comment: Great question. The confusion is that a form field that you see in a PDF is both a form field and an Annotation (of Widget type). The Annotation Widget is the visual appearance of a form field. In other words a single form field (e.g. first_name) can be repeated on multiple pages, by using multiple Widget annotations. But all these annotation widgets will show the same value (though they can differ in color/font). So the interactiveForms sample I posted above is the correct one, since you want to find and set field values. The annotations just reflect the value. Feel free to contact support.